# Repository pattern in RxJava2

Tags: android, repository-pattern, rx-java2

If you are using the `Repository` pattern and loading from local and remote, does it make sense to have the local return `Maybe<T>` and remote return `Single<T>` in `RxJava2`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Definitely! You could make your disk/memory cache return a `Maybe` and if it is empty, switch to return from the `Single` network source. Makes it cleaner and logical since DB might or might not return anything and the network response is mostly always a Single. Your final response could be a `Single`.

An example would be:

```
@Override
public Single<E> get(long id) {
    return fetchFromDb(id)
            .switchIfEmpty(fetchFromNetwork(id))
            .subscribeOn(schedulerProvider.io());
}
```

I have used it like the above previously. In fact, the above is heavily influenced by New York Times, [Store library](https://github.com/NYTimes/Store)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I had the same case, while I was applying rxjava2 to the repository pattern.
I didn't want convert all my retrofit service from returning Single to Maybe,

For your question, just use toMaybe()

My example of Rxjava2 repository pattern is following:

```
protected Maybe<Foo> loadDataFromCache() {
    Foo foo = cachedDataHelper.getFoo();
    return foo != null ? Maybe.just(foo) : Maybe.empty();
}

public Single<Foo> loadDataFromMultipleRepos () {
    Maybe<Foo> apiCallObservable = new FooCallRx().getAPIObservable(context).toMaybe();
    Maybe<Foo> cacheObservable = loadDataFromCache();

    return Maybe.concat(cacheObservable, apiCallObservable)
            .toSingle();
}
```